Webdriver wait variable null only when running testng.xml file but works fine when the Alltest class is run individually
Im just learning testng and am having trouble executing groups. When I run the Alltests class individually I have no issues and it completes the tests successfully. But when I try to run it through the testng.xml file I get the following error.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.until(java.util.function.Function)" because "this.wait" is null
Ive tried a few things to see if I could identify the issue but was unsuccessful. I tried a print statement in the setup method to see if it even went through that part but it didnt print. So it doesnt even go through the baseclass?
I also tried a few alternative tests to see if there were any issues with testng. I ran a few print statements in a set up and extended class and it worked. But when I tried it with groups i got a similar error. So i think there might be an issue with how ive done the groups?
Also Ive checked a few other articles and none seem to help, Ive tried chatgpt too and even that thing has no idea whats wrong.
Please check my code and let me know if I have made any mistakes.
My BaseClass
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import java.time.Duration;


public class BaseClass {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected WebDriverWait wait;

    Duration timeout = Duration.ofSeconds(50);

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {

        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);

        driver.get("http://localhost/Work%20management%20system/");
        System.out.println("Driver and wait initialized.");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }


}

My Alltests class
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;



public class Alltests extends BaseClass{

private void loginProcess(String username, String password){

    WebElement login = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div/center[2]/a")));
    login.click();

    WebElement usernamefield = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/input[1]")));
    usernamefield.sendKeys(username);

    WebElement passwordfield = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/input[2]")));
    passwordfield.sendKeys(password);

    WebElement submit = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/button")));
    submit.click();

}

@Test(groups = {"loginTests"})
public void shouldfail(){

    loginProcess("danny12@gmail.com", "doughnuts");


    boolean isErrorMessagePresent = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div"))).isDisplayed();

    boolean isAnnouncementAbsent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div")).isEmpty();

    Assert.assertTrue(isErrorMessagePresent, "Error message should be present");

    Assert.assertTrue(isAnnouncementAbsent, "Announcement button should be absent");

    if (isErrorMessagePresent && isAnnouncementAbsent){

        System.out.print("Test case passed access denied");
    }

}



@Test(groups = {"loginTests"})
public void shouldAlsoFail(){

    loginProcess("danny12@gmail.com", "danny1234");


    boolean isErrorMessagePresent = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div"))).isDisplayed();

    boolean isAnnouncementAbsent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div")).isEmpty();

    Assert.assertTrue(isErrorMessagePresent, "Error message should be present");

    Assert.assertTrue(isAnnouncementAbsent, "Logout button should be absent");

    if (isErrorMessagePresent && isAnnouncementAbsent){

        System.out.print("Test case passed, access denied");
    }
}



@Test(groups = {"loginTests"})
public void willFail(){

    loginProcess("danny@gmail.com", "danny128934");


    boolean isErrorMessagePresent = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div"))).isDisplayed();

    boolean isAnnouncementAbsent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div")).isEmpty();

    Assert.assertTrue(isErrorMessagePresent, "Error message should be present");

    Assert.assertTrue(isAnnouncementAbsent, "Announcement button should be absent");

    if (isErrorMessagePresent && isAnnouncementAbsent){

        System.out.print("Test case passed access denied");
    }

}



@Test(groups = {"loginTests"})
public void accessAllowed(){

    loginProcess("danny@gmail.com", "danny1234");


    boolean isAnnouncementPresent = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div"))).isDisplayed();

    Assert.assertTrue(isAnnouncementPresent, "Announcements should be present");

    if (isAnnouncementPresent){

        System.out.print("Test case passed access is granted");
    }


}

}
My tesng.xml file
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test Group">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="loginTests"/>

            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="Alltests"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>

and my pom file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>LoginTests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version> 4.21.0 </version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

